# disabling webtatic repo spitting back errors on centos

Tags: centos, php

I installed the "webtatic" repo for PHP and it's caused nothing but trouble.  When I try to run `yum --disablerepo=webtatic distro-sync` it returns this:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0 from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package compat-mysql51-5.1.54-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0 from install of mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package compat-mysql51-5.1.54-1.el6.remi.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

How can I disable this repo and get rid of the problem?  Output of `ls` on `/etc/yum.repos.d`

```
[root@ltfs1968 yum.repos.d]# ls
atomic.repo                epel.repo          r1soft.repo  rhel-source.repo      webtatic-archive.repo  webtatic-testing.repo
```

My goal is to get rid of this and get back onto PHP 5.3 on the default repo.

Answer (score 1):

You also installed some packages from the `remi` repository, but you disabled -- and removed! -- that repository.

I'm going to guess that you actually *want* to keep the newer version of MySQL that you got from remi, and advise you to put the repo back and enable it.